# Inter tables query: I need to build a query that filter data base on conditions in two other tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables as following

```
data 
timestamp   : col1: col2: col3
-------------------------------- 
2017-03-12  : 2.2 : 3.3: 5.1 
2017-06-10  : 1.2 : 1.3: 2.1

offset 
starttime  : endtime    : col1 : col2 : col3
------------------------------------------ 
2017-03-10 : 2017-03-13 : 0.5  :  0.7 : 0.1 
2017-06-09 : 2017-06-12 : 1    :   2  :  3

flag 
timestamp   : col1: col2: col3
------------------------------- 
2017-03-12  : 0   : 0   : 1 
2017-06-10  : 1   : 0   : 1
```

I wan to build a query that gives me the folowing result:

```
data.timestamp,
offset.starttime,
offset.endtime, 
CASE WHEN flag.col1=0 < THEN NULL ELSE data.Col1 + offset.Col1 AS COL1 END,
CASE WHEN flag.col2=0 < THEN NULL ELSE data.Col2 + offset.Col2 AS COL2 END,
CASE WHEN flag.col3=0 < THEN NULL ELSE data.Col3 + offset.Col3 AS COL3 END
where data.TimeStamp Between offsett.StarTime and offset.EndTime
```

in our case for instance

the result would be: considering both data and offset table only the result is the following:

```
TimeStamp   : offset.StartTime : offset.EndTime : COL1 : COL2 : COL3
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
2017-03-12  :    2017-03-10    :    2017-03-13  : 2.7   : 4.0 : 5.2 
2017-06-10  :    2017-06-09    :    2017-06-12  : 2.2   : 2.3 : 5.1
```

But by adding the third condition with the flag table, the final result will be:

```
TimeStamp   : offset.StartTime : offset.EndTime : COL1 : COL2 : COL3
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
2017-03-12  :    2017-03-10    :    2017-03-13  : NULL : NULL : 5.2 
2017-06-10  :    2017-06-09    :    2017-06-12  : 2.2  : NULL : 5.1

Is it possible to build such a query thanks
```

Comment: SQL only needs =  not ==

Comment: you're right wasn't meant as final statement but and explanation about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem you just need a simple join:

```
select
    data.timestamp,
    offset.starttime,
    offset.endtime, 
    CASE WHEN flag.col1=0 < THEN NULL ELSE data.Col1 + offset.Col1 AS COL1 END as Col1,
    CASE WHEN flag.col2=0 < THEN NULL ELSE data.Col2 + offset.Col2 AS COL2 END as Col2,
    CASE WHEN flag.col3=0 < THEN NULL ELSE data.Col3 + offset.Col3 AS COL3 END as Col3
from data
join offset on data.TimeStamp between offset.StarTime and offset.EndTime
join flag on flag.TimeStamp = data.TimeStamp
```

I recommend renaming your `TimeStamp` columns to `Date`, because they store dates not timestamps.